# Extracting certain regions in the image for further classification

Tags: image, image-processing, machine-learning, classification

I have a number of images (as well as the original data sources) that exhibit specific features. Some of them have distinct vertical/horizontal regions, as shown in the following figure or simply "blobs"/concentrations of points in very specific regions.

[image]

These images are associated with specific labels/classes, for instance, a label "A" exhibits very characteristic horizontal lines (like those marked in figure) at y = 700 and y = 150. Those images that belong to class "B", exhibit vertical lines at x = 200, 260 and 370, class "C"..., and so on.

Besides these known/labelled classes, I have a bunch of images that exhibit one of these features, or their combination.

My goal is to use these known classes to train some ML algorithm in order to further use it for classifying those images that do not have any labels. I understand that I need to somehow extract these particularities (vertical/horizontal lines, blobs of high point density that usually occur in the upper-right corner of the image, or in the (x,y) region of (250-400, 800-1500) and so on). Next, I would  need to train some ML algorithm with these features, and only then use the trained system for classif.

I have been looking and playing with some tools for 3-4 days now (like PIL, with different blurring, smoothing and edge detecting techniques, or MDP's Gaussian classifiers and many posts on stackoverflow). The problem is that I cannot for a clear "solution process + appropriate tools" combination.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could guide me a bit more into the techniques for extracting these very specific/weird features from images (or even original datasets), and/or tools to use.

Comment: What does the y and x axis mean?

Comment: x and y are different flow record parameters, like average number of bytes, or a number of constituent packets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have the feature vectors for your samples (training data).

If this is so and you are only looking for a machine learning algorithm implementation, I would suggest you to use Support Vector Machines SVM. A popular implementation called SVM-light is available free of cost for your use. http://svmlight.joachims.org/
Please note that the above site gives a 2-class implementation. If you need a multi-class SVM you can get it from http://svmlight.joachims.org/svm_multiclass.html

Yet few more popular classifiers are

- Nearest Neighbour classifier
- C4.5 Decision Trees
- Neural Network